# Can't save my files in Arabic Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unicode, laravel-5

My App is getting an attribute from database in arabic language, when i'm trying to save my file and rename it according to this attribute i'm getting these characters (Ø³ÙŠÙ†2Ù…Ø¨Ù†ÙŠ Ø¨) instead of (مبني ب) however, when i try to print it, the result is (مبني ب) not (Ø³ÙŠÙ†2Ù…Ø¨Ù†ÙŠ Ø¨)
Here is my code for saving the file:

```
    $project = Project::find(1);; //Model Project
    $destinationPath = 'ProjectPictures/' .$project->name . '/';//the name attribute is in arabic 
    $file =$request->file('image'); //image to be saved in arabic named directory
    $file->move($destinationPath, 'image.jpg');
```

I'm using utf8_general_ci for the table collation and utf8 for default charset, phpmyadmin, and im using Windows 8 for my OS

Answer (score 1):

use **iconv** function

عن تجربة اتحدث ونحلت معي

```
$fileName=iconv('utf-8','windows-1256', $file->getClientOriginalName());
$file->storeAs("images/"), $fileName);
```

ادعيلي

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$project = Project::find(1); //Model Project
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($project->name);
$destinationPath= iconv($encoding, "UTF-8", "ProjectPictures/".$project->name);
$file =$request->file('image'); //image to be saved in arabic named directory
$file->move($destinationPath, 'image.jpg');
```

Comment: The same result as before :/

Comment: I've printed mb_detect_encoding($project->name) and the result was UTF-8,
 but somehow when i'm trying to save a file on disk using $project->name
 it gives me this strange strings like(Ø³ÙŠÙ†2Ù…Ø¨Ù†ÙŠ Ø¨)

Comment: is your file an image file? and and are you trying to encode the file name or folder name?

Comment: try setting a header like `header("Content-Type:text/html;  charset=utf-8"); `

Comment: its a directory not a file ,and the problem that the destination path is already in UTF-8 but somehow it is automatically decoded when trying to save a file by that name